# Word 2013: How to have a different heading in the navigation pane

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I've created a word document with lots of headings in the pages and these headings show up very well in the  navigation pane. The issue is I have a cover page as the document's first page, I want the heading of the cover page to appear as "Cover" in the navigation pane. I can very well achieve this by creating a heading with the text "Cover" on the cover page. But you know nobody types "Cover" on the cover page. And it is even odd to do that. So is there any way I can display the heading of the cover page as "Cover" in the navigation pane without actually creating the heading with the text "Cover" on the page.

**EDIT**: The cover page I've mentioned is a regular page and not any of the pre-designed cover page provided by Word

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible without the word actually being on the page. That being said, Covers generally have a lot of white space. You could do this: In some of the white space, type the word "COVER" with one of the heading styles. Highlight the word "COVER" after confirming it's in the navigation pane. Once highlighted, change text color to white. This way, it'll show on the navigation pane, but won't be clearly visible on the page.